# How to investigate what is making traffic?

Tags: 20.04, openvpn

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with disabled upgrades and no cronjobs at home in VirtualBox.

There is an enp0s3 and a tun0 for an OpenVPN connection to a LTE/mobile connection far away (to a MikroTik device). The LTE connection is traffic limited/month, so I have to be careful with the traffic.

If I check, I can see tun0 had 80 MByte of traffic (I generated it!) and enp0s3 had 1.6 GBytes since last rebooot (I have no idea what is this about 1.6 GByte minus 80 MBytes).

Although the traffic limited traffic probably only counts via the tun0 device, but still curious!

**The Question**: how can I investigate what is causing the traffic on enp0s3?

update#1: I checked to generate traffic with a "yes > yes.txt" to the vbox share, but that didn't counted as traffic in the ifconfig.

Comment: ...and I'm going to assume you meant you disabled "unattended upgrades" which are totally different from the feature that pops up on your screen in the "software updater"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo nethogs enp0s3` will let you you designate the device.

```
    NetHogs version 0.8.5-2build2

    PID USER     PROGRAM                                              DEV        SENT      RECEIVED       
  47562 wu-tang  /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                             enp0s3      1.181       0.184 KB/sec
  71120 _apt     /usr/lib/apt/methods/http                            enp0s3      0.121       0.097 KB/sec
  48131 wu-tang  ..nap/opera/170/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/opera enp0s3      0.013       0.022 KB/sec
      ? root     unknown TCP                                                      0.000       0.000 KB/sec
```

it is not installed by default.

`sudo apt install nethogs`

Comment: nethogs showed it was SNAPD that caused the traffic, many thanks! (maybe update your question with the "trace mode", so "nethogs -t > trace.log" will output the logs which you can grep!

Comment: additionally fwupd did some strage high traffic too...

Answer (score 0):

Use `tcpdump` to review the traffic currently passing in the interface:

```
tcpdump -n -i tun0 | tee -a traffic.log
```

`-n` disables name resolution, `-a` appends lines to the log file. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to stop the capturing; after that you can use `less -S traffic.log` to check all the traffic captured (`-S` disables wrapping lines).

`tcpdump` accepts filters to only capture some packets, like `host 8.8.8.8` or `port 53`. Read about them with `man pcap-filter`.

Other useful tool for checking current bandwith and traffic source/destinations is `íftop`.